# What is it called when a person pronounces the letter t in the word "metal" as something more similar to a d sound?

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation, dialects, voicing, allophones

What is it called when a person pronounces the letter t in the word "metal" as something more similar to a d sound? And what is it called when a person stresses the t in the word "metal" to be more clearly like a regular t than like a d (like the difference between how an American says "metal" and how an Englishman might say that word)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The phenomenon is known as "flapping", and the result, transcribed as [ɾ], is a "flap". It also applies to /d/, but people notice it most when applied to /t/ since the result is more different compared to /d/. You might call is a "fast d".

If an American were to say [mɛtʰəl] very carefully, that could be called hyperarticulation, that is, aiming to stop a rule of the language from applying by slowing your speech down. I have learned to suppress flapping when I am eliciting linguistic data from people who don't speak American English, they get confused if I pronounce "metal" or "medal" ordinarily. It is generally difficult for Americans to suppress flapping. If you're asking what it's called when British English speaker *don't* flap, that's just "talking", there's no term for not applying a rule that is not in your dialect.

Answer (score 3):

Flapping applies to intervocalic syllable offset alveolar stops.  This formulation assumes some things that are less than obvious.  For one thing, it assumes that syllabic and glide r count as vowels, to account for flapping in such words as "dirty" "barter" ?"cortical".  And that the off-glides of diphthongs also count as vowels: "routing" "boating" "goiter".

Another assumption: syllabic resonants r, l, m, n are derived from phonemic forms with preceding vowels, which have been lost: "border", "little", "bottle", "bottom", "button" (this last only in dialects where the t does not become glottal stop).

It's also assumed that intervocalic consonants before unstressed vowels belong to the syllable of the preceding vowel. The t of your example "metallic" is in the wrong syllable to be flapped, since t is in the syllable of the following stressed vowel.

Comment: I like your explanation since you've explained the pronunciations of words like 'party' and 'dirty', they also have *flap t*. My impression is that; the 't' becomes weak and is influenced by the preceding 'r' sound so it sounds like *flap t*. But now it's clear. I've heard that American 'r' is more like a vowel. Is that true?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Yes, I agree that flapping is a weakening process.  It is one of several  weakening processes which affect syllable offset consonants.  It is also assimilatory, since it changes t d from obstruents, which are naturally voiceless, into sonorants, which are naturally voiced,  The surrounding vowels that are required for flapping are also sonorants.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Some people think that the 't' in 'party' disappears and becomes **r** sound (in AmE) but I disagree with that because I can hear the stop sound in 'party'. If the 't' disappears it becomes 'parry' which is very different than 'party' (having the stop sound).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul So you don't like "pahrry of the first part", but how about "durry ol' man"?  Deletion of the flap resulting from t is possible for some of us, but it requires a whole new level of sloppiness.  It might happen only in drunk speech, and is less likely for erudite words, like "vitamin", "barter".

Answer (score 2):

The phenomenon you're talking about is called *T-flapping* (and its opposite is, I suppose, the *absence of T-flapping*).

Many Americans pronounce the `/t/` and `/d/` sounds ("alveolar stops") as something linguists write as `[ɾ]` (an "alveolar flap") when they come between two vowels. Most Brits don't do this.

Comment: "T-flapping" is not a great name, since all three alveolar stops flap in the relevant dialects, t, d, n.  Not just t.

Comment: @GregLee True, but OP was asking specifically about /t/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the comments above have summarized this perfectly. It is a type of flapping..

'water'

=

wader in some American dialect. This is a flap also.

wa'er in Cockney dialects with a glottal stop.